# Low performance of php array with variable key

Tags: php, arrays

So I've got a problem with performance of arrays in php when I use variable as a key. 
I'm working with a lot of data and when I use a method that looks something like this

```
private function get_foo_by_id($foo_id) {
    return $this->array_of_foos[$foo_id];
}
```

it takes +-17seconds to finish the procedure. But when I replace the variable `$foo_id` for a constant, like this

```
private function get_foo_by_id($foo_id) {
    return $this->array_of_foos[64];
}
```

then it takes only +-3seconds. 
Where is the problem? I thought that seek operation by a key in php arrays should be O(1).

Comment: How are you benchmarking this?

Comment: with `time()` function

Comment: Isn't $foo_id string "64" instead of being int 64?

Comment: It is an integer

Comment: I don't think you provided us with enough information to give you any kind of explanation for what you're experiencing. Even for a very large array both these functions should return within roughly the same time. You could try to cast `$foo_id` though  `$this->array_of_foos[(int)$foo_id];` just to be sure.

Comment: I'm sure it is an integer, I tested it with `gettype()` function

Comment: I tried to call the first function with a constant 64 and the results is same (17s)

Comment: I just created my own benchmark for this: https://pastebin.com/K0At9362 Result: https://pastebin.com/8PTQMCTc So lookup from variable is some 30% slower. Judging by your script taking several seconds for the call, I suspect that your dataset is so large the OS has to start swapping, adding additional time for memory management that PHP can't do anything about.

Comment: Ok, so I'll try to optimise it somehow. Thanks for the answers.